# how to export postgresql database table into mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to get data from a Postgres database, but I am totally new to using Postgres.
I am here to ask my question to get some ideas from the best answer on how can I can do this. If possible, I'd also like a simple demo.

### My question

I have one `postgreSql` database and I want to `import them into my pgPhpAdmin` using `Commands`.

How can I do so?
Please Help me Out with this.

**How can I export a Postgresql database table into mySQL ?**

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing records from PostgreSQL to MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737063/importing-records-from-postgresql-to-mysql)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189784/how-to-migrate-database-from-postgres-to-mysql) also shows a lot more research on your same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done a Postgres to mySQL migration before, but I know you can use the `pg_dump` tool to get a generated textfile of SQL statements you can use to reconstruct your database later.

[The official Postgres documentation on pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/backup-dump.html)

You'd run this on Linux by opening up a terminal and typing in `pg_dump` at the prompt.

This dumps the default `postgres` database.

To get the dump of a database called `TECH` into a file called `TECH.PGSQL` you'd do:

```
pg_dump TECH > TECH.PGSQL
```

[The `>` symbol is a redirection of the output of `pg_dump` into the specified file name `TECH.PGSQL`](http://linuxtutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=21).

I'm afraid I don't have any experience with pgPhpAdmin or doing this on Windows, so I can't help you there. I suggest that you look around for how to perform a database dump in Postgres on Windows if that's the OS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

My [open-source](https://github.com/calmitchell617/sqlpipe) tool [SQLpipe](https://sqlpipe.com) can transfer the result of a query from one database to another. PostgreSQL and MySQL are both [supported systems](https://docs.sqlpipe.com/supported-systems/).

Here is a guide on using SQLpipe to [transfer data from PostgreSQL to MySQL](https://sqlpipe.com/transfer-data-from-postgresql-to-mysql/). A quick summary:

1. [Download SQLpipe](https://sqlpipe.com/downloads). It is an executable program with no dependencies.
2. Grant permission to run SQLpipe with `chmod +x sqlpipe`, if required by your operating system.
3. Transfer data with a single CLI command, like this:

```
sqlpipe transfer \
  --source-ds-type "postgresql" \
  --source-hostname "your-postgresql-hostname" \
  --source-port 5432 \
  --source-db-name "your-postgresql-db-name" \
  --source-username "your-postgresql-username" \
  --source-password "your-postgresql-password"
  --target-ds-type "mysql" \
  --target-hostname "your-mysql-hostname" \
  --target-port 3306 \
  --target-db-name "your-mysql-db-name" \
  --target-username "your-mysql-username" \
  --target-password "your-mysql-password" \
  --target-table "name-of-table-to-insert-into" \
  --overwrite \
  --query "select * from public.users"
```